# Make first-child full width in another div

Tags: css

We can simply give `width: 100%;` to `first-child` and `flex-grow: 1;` to all the other items.

However, how can we achieve them same effect but `div`'s are seperated? `h1` and `<p>` are in the left column and an `<img>` in the right one. We want the `h1` to be the full width and place the `<p>` and `<img>` next to each other.

See [Fiddle](https://codepen.io/sbalieev/pen/eYKmYgd) for example. Red is what the structure I have and blue is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
}

p, img {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  position: relative;
}

.item h1:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
}

.item p,
.item img {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.items:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.items:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Added */
h1 {
  left: 0;
}

#change-p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

#img-item {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p id="change-p">Lorem ipsum data flow.. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="img-item" class="item">
    <img id="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="placeholder" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add row-reverse so the img and p changes places but header still starts from begin position? (see updated fiddle for the current structure)

Comment: I edited my answer. Couldn't make it with `row-reverse`.

Comment: it is not showing correctly on my end

Comment: Did you check it in full-page mode? It's because you set `#container { width: 20%; }`.

Comment: Yes, I want to switch the P and img from position

Comment: It works. Remove CSS that I added and you'll see that without it `<p>` is on the right and `<img>` is on the left.